# Im getting an error at cellForRowAt and im not sure why

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, swift5

I am getting an error in the function `cellForRowAt`

> Cannot assign value of type 'Product' to type 'String?'

Is `cell.textLabel?.text = product` the issue that's causing this error?

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let product = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = product

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)


        return cell
    }
```

Comment: `cell.textLabel?.text = product`, `product` is an instance of `Product`, but you're trying to assign it to a property which expects an instance of `String`.  Maybe use of the `Product` properties, like `cell.textLabel?.text = product.item`

Comment: use like cell.textLabel?.text = product.item or product.price

Comment: i get a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT when i run it

Comment: let product = items[indexPath.row]  print product in the next line and see what is it's value

Comment: ^that doesnt work, i just tried @vijeesh

Comment: @MG3 you are trying to set product type to String type. That will not work. you need to access the product model's properties and format accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cell.textLabel?.text` can only show a `String` object, not other objects.

It will be `product.item` or `product.price` or `product.salesPrice` or all in one line. (based on your requirement).

Make sure the value of `product` is not nil.

```
cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.item) \(product.price) \(product.salesPrice)"
```

**The full code you can try this:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIAdaptivePresentationControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var items:[Product]? = []

    // VIEW LOAD
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
            self.isModalInPresentation = true
        }

        getData()
    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        getData()
    }

    override func viewDidDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidDisappear(true)
        storeData()
    }
    override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
    // ADD ITEMS
    @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Product Information", message: nil, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addTextField { (itemTextField) in
            itemTextField.placeholder = "Item"
        }
        alert.addTextField { (priceTextField) in
            priceTextField.placeholder = "Price"
        }

        alert.addTextField { (salePriceTextField) in
            salePriceTextField.placeholder = "Sale Price"
        }

        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: .default) { (_) in
            let item = alert.textFields?[0].text ?? ""
            let price = alert.textFields?[1].text ?? ""
            let salesPrice = alert.textFields?[2].text ?? ""

            let product = Product(item: item, price: price, salesPrice: salesPrice)
            self.addProduct(product)
        }

        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true)
        storeData()

    }

    func addProduct(_ product: Product) {
        let index = 0
        items?.insert(product, at: index)

        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .left)
        storeData()
    }

    //STORE DATA
    func storeData() {
        UserDefaultUtil.saveData(products: items)
    }

    func getData() {
        items = UserDefaultUtil.loadProducts()

    }

}

//EXTENSION
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items!.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell()
        let product = items![indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = "\(product.item!) \(product.price) \(product.salesPrice)"

        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.92, green:0.92, blue:0.92, alpha:1.0)
        cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)
        tableView.separatorColor = UIColor(red:0.13, green:0.13, blue:0.13, alpha:1.0)


        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        guard editingStyle == .delete else { return }
        items?.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .fade)
        storeData()
    }
}

class UserDefaultUtil {

    private static let Key = "savedData"

    private static func archivePeople(people : [Product]) -> NSData {

        return NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: people as NSArray) as NSData
    }

    static func loadProducts() -> [Product]? {

        if let unarchivedObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: Key) as? Data {

            return NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: unarchivedObject as Data) as? [Product]
        }

        return nil
    }

    static func saveData(products : [Product]?) {
        let archivedObject = archivePeople(people: products!)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(archivedObject, forKey: Key)
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
    }

}

class Product: NSObject, NSCoding {
    var item: String?
    var price: String?
    var salesPrice: String?

    required init(item:String, price:String, salesPrice: String) {
        self.item = item
        self.price = price
        self.salesPrice = salesPrice
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        self.item = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "item") as? String
        self.price = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "price") as? String
        self.salesPrice = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "salesPrice") as? String
    }

    public func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder) {
        aCoder.encode(item, forKey: "item")
        aCoder.encode(price, forKey: "price")
        aCoder.encode(salesPrice, forKey: "salesPrice")
    }
}
```

Comment: Please set all exception breakpoint and run again. This will mark the exact exception point.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Seems like the value of product is nil. Make sure the `product` is not nil before setting the value to the label.

Comment: how do i make sure its not? i never set it to nil

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203002/discussion-between-faysal-ahmed-and-mg3).

Comment: wont let me type in chat, but i cant use 11.0 and 4.2. it doesnt work and says convert to swift 5

Comment: it wont let me type in chat anymore @Faysal Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

`cell.textLabel?.text = product` 
 try doing `product.item` or `product.price` or `product.salesPrice.`

`cell.textLabel?.text` is expecting a string what you are setting is another type.

Comment: Binary operator '/' cannot be applied to two 'String' operands. thats the error i get

Comment: check the answer now. I modified and that  will not cause confusion for you.

Comment: i get a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT error when i run it and only using cell.textLabel?.text = product.item

Comment: @MG3 what do you want to print in the text field?

Comment: i posted a picture at the top for you, thats what i want it to look like

Answer (score 0):

First of all reuse cells.

**Never create cells with the default initializer.**

Assign an identifier to the cell in Interface Builder (for example `MainCell`), then replace

```
let cell = UITableViewCell()
```

with

```
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MainCell", for: indexPath)
```

---

The error is very clear. As already mentioned in other answers you have to assign the value of a **property** of `Product` to the label

```
cell.textLabel?.text = product.title
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't create cells with default initializer

Assign an identifier to the tableview's cell in interface builder

```
let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
```

you have to assign the property of Product to label's text

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        let product = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = product.price // product.item, product.salesPrice
        return cell
    }
```